# Generating 3D plots in R with arbitrary data points and viewpoints

Tags: r, plot

I want an R function that will let me do the following two things simultaneously:

1. Plot arbitrary piecewise functions like scatterplot3d. That is, it should let me specify a arbitrary set of 3d coordinates at which points will be plotted.
2. Let me set the viewpoint of the graph to arbitrary angles along both axises, like persp.

plot3d is not acceptable as it only allows manual adjustment of the plots once they are generated. I want to be able to script this.

Comment: Actually you can specify the viewpoint in `rgl::plot3d` without doing in manually: see `?par3d`, `?matrices`. Don't have time to do a worked example right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a pckage I'm currently developing, [addendum](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=1130), there is a function `plot4d` that gives a neat example if how to do that with `rgl`. You don't have to use the package for it: just rip the source of the function.

(note: you may get 2 warnings when loading the package - this is because of a minor glitch in the otherwise beautiful `glmnet` package, and doesn't break anything.)